# Scala - TrieMap vs Vector

Tags: scala, data-structures, hash, trie

I read that `TrieMap` in scala is based on has array mapped trie, whike `Vector` reads bit mapped vector trie.

Are both darastructures backed by the same idea of a hash trie or is there a difference between these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some similarities, but fundamentally they are different data structures:

## Vector

There is no hashing involved in `Vector`. The index directly describes the path into the tree. And of course, the occupied indices of a vector are consecutive.

Disregarding all the trickery with the display pointers in the production implementation of `scala.collection.immutable.Vector`, every branch node in a vector except for the last one at a level has *the same number of children* (32 in case of the scala `Vector`). That allows indexing using simple bit manipulation. The downside is that splicing elements in the middle of a vector is expensive.

[image]

## HashMap

In a HashTrieMap, the hash code is the path into the tree. That means that the occupied indices are *not consecutive*, but evenly distributed. This requires a different encoding of the tree branch nodes.

In a `HashTrieMap`, a branch node has *up to* 32 children (But if you have a very bad hash code distribution it is entirely possible to have a branch node with only one child). There is an `Int` bitmap to encode which child corresponds to which position, which means that looking up values in a HashTrieMap requires frequent calls to [Integer.bitCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-), which fortunately is a CPU intrinsic on modern CPUs.

[image]

Here is a fun project that allows you to look at the internals of scala data structures such as `Vector` and `HashMap`: https://github.com/stanch/reftree

The images in this answer were generated using this project.